# How to check if an application installed or not in pc from asp.net web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to open a windows application from my web application  and I know how to do that. The problem is I can't determine whether the application is installed or not .Currently I'm using the following code for checking,

```
    var win= window.open(url, 'send', 'width=100,height=100,top=1,left=1,resizable=yes', '1');
     if(win==null || win.closed==true)
       {
        alert("Application not installed.");
       }
```

and its working ok but the problem is if the popup is blocked then I get null value then the alert appears even the application is installed. So is there any way to check if an application installed or not in pc from web application

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var win= window.open(url, 'send', 'width=100,height=100,top=1,left=1,resizable=yes', '1');           

if(!win|| win.closed || typeof win.closed=='undefined') 
{ 
 //POPUP BLOCKED
 return;
}
if(win==null || win.closed==true)
{
    alert("Application not installed.");
}
```